# Compute $ \int\frac{ x}{x-\sqrt{x²+2x+4}}dx$ using Euler substition

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

> Compute $ \int\frac{ x}{x-\sqrt{x²+2x+4}}dx$ using Euler substition

I have tried to find the antiderivative of this function :$\frac{ x}{x-\sqrt{x²+2x+4}}$ using the substitution $x=\frac{u^2-4}{2(u+1)}$ for elminate the problem of square root because it is incomplete but really i have got a complicated form , then how do i find : 
 $\displaystyle \int\frac{ x}{x-\sqrt{x²+2x+4}}dx$ by this substitution or if there is any other simple method ?

Comment: Expand the result into simple fractions $15/(4 (u + 1)) + 15/(4 (u + 1)^2) + 9/(4 (u + 1)^3) - 4/u + 1/4$.

Comment: $x^2+2x+4=3\left(\left(\frac{x+1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)^2+1\right)$ and consider hyperbolic functions.